# SVNKit to find diff between two files stored at separate locations with separate revision numbers

Tags: java, svn, diff, svnkit

I am writing a Java program using the SVNKit API, and I need to use the correct class or call in the API that would allow me to find the diff between files stored in separate locations.

1st file:

> https://abc.edc.xyz.corp/svn/di-edc/tags/ab-cde-fgh-axsym-1.0.0/src/site/apt/releaseNotes.apt

2nd file:

> https://abc.edc.xyz.corp/svn/di-edc/tags/ab-cde-fgh-axsym-1.1.0/src/site/apt/releaseNotes.apt

I have used the listed API calls to generate the diff output, but I am unsuccessful so far.

```
DefaultSVNDiffGenerator diffGenerator = new DefaultSVNDiffGenerator();
diffGenerator.displayFileDiff("", file1, file2, "10983", "8971", "text", "text/plain", output);

diffClient.doDiff(svnUrl1, SVNRevision.create(10868), svnUrl2, SVNRevision.create(8971), SVNDepth.IMMEDIATES, false, System.out);
```

Can anyone provide guidance on the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks correct. But prefer using the new API:

```
    final SvnOperationFactory svnOperationFactory = new SvnOperationFactory();
    try {
        final ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        final SvnDiffGenerator diffGenerator = new SvnDiffGenerator();
        diffGenerator.setBasePath(new File(""));

        final SvnDiff diff = svnOperationFactory.createDiff();
        diff.setSources(SvnTarget.fromURL(url1, svnRevision1), SvnTarget.fromURL(url2, svnRevision1));
        diff.setDiffGenerator(diffGenerator);
        diff.setOutput(byteArrayOutputStream);
        diff.run();
    } finally {
        svnOperationFactory.dispose();
    }
```

Comment: SVNKit has some tests you can use them as examples. The code above I've copy-pasted from DiffTest (and removed test-related code).